# Haskell: Read a JSON (aeson) value which was produced with show. Error messages

Tags: haskell

I have a JSON record which I have shown and I try to read the result back; actually I pasted the output back into the code (as `o1`). This should give the record back, but I get an error message to compile.

Should `show` not print the Haskell code which would reproduce the given value?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where      -- must have Main (main) or Main where

import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Text
import           Data.Map

main :: IO ()
main = do  -- with tests in other modules
    putStrLn (show val)

val :: Value
val = object ["boolean" .= True, "numbers" .= [1, 2, 3 :: Int]]

    -- copied output to read in - does not compile
o1 =
    Object
        (fromList
            [ ("boolean", Bool True)
            , ("numbers", Array [Number 1.0, Number 2.0, Number 3.0])
            ]
        ) :: Value
```

The errors are:

```
 • Couldn't match type ‘Map [Char] Value’
                     with ‘unordered-containers-0.2.10.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                             Text Value’
      Expected type: Object
        Actual type: Map [Char] Value
    • In the first argument of ‘Object’, namely
...
ClassMain.hs:26:33: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Value]’ with ‘Data.Vector.Vector Value’
      Expected type: Array
        Actual type: [Value]
    • In the first argument of ‘Array’, namely
        ‘[Number 1.0, Number 2.0, Number 3.0]’
      In the expression: Array [Number 1.0, Number 2.0, Number 3.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

> Should `show` not print the Haskell code which would reproduce the given value?

Not quite. This often is the case, but IIRC, the 'law' that `show` should follow is that if the type also has a `read` instance, then `show` and `read` should be able to round-trip.

But first, there's a few problems with the code, as implied by the compiler error. If you consider [the documentation of Object](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Object), you'll see that it's a type alias for `HashMap Text Value`. `HashMap` is defined in `Data.HashMap.Strict`, not `Data.Map`, so change your import of `Data.Map` to:

```
import           Data.HashMap.Strict
```

That addresses that particular compiler error, but now you get a new problem:

```
* Couldn't match type `[Value]' with `Data.Vector.Vector Value'
  Expected type: Array
    Actual type: [Value]
* In the first argument of `Array', namely
    `[Number 1.0, Number 2.0, Number 3.0]'
  In the expression: Array [Number 1.0, Number 2.0, Number 3.0]
  In the expression:
    ("numbers", Array [Number 1.0, Number 2.0, Number 3.0])
```

This happens because the `Array` data constructor of `Value` takes an `Array`, which is a type alias for `Vector Value`.

The `show` instance for `Vector` does, indeed, print a `Vector` as a list:

```
*Q62512071 Data.Vector> show $ generate 3 id
"[0,1,2]"
```

It does, however, nicely round-trip if you read it back:

```
*Q62512071 Data.Vector> read $ show $ generate 3 id :: Vector Int
[0,1,2]
```

It turns out that, indeed, you can do the same with `val`:

```
*Q62512071> read $ show val :: Value
Object (fromList [("boolean",Bool True),("numbers",Array [Number 1.0,Number 2.0,Number 3.0])])
```

In general, however, when you work with Aeson, you're supposed to work with its `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` API, not `Show` and `Read`.

Comment: I will add that if you're trying to copy the `show` output directly into code, instead of using `read`, you will need to enable the `OverloadedLists` language extension to make sure `[Number 1.0,Number 2.0,Number 3.0]` is processed as an `Array` instead of a list.

Comment: Thank you both for the very helpful and valuable answers, which I read carefully. I understand (and have used) ToJSON and FromJSON but in my regressionTest system I need to use read/show to store values on disk. Thus your pointers are crucial.  -- I could switch the regression test to use JSON everywhere, which I will consider when I redesign it.

Comment: When I try the advice, especially the one from @Rik Van Toor, other errors appear: the `val = object ..` cannot match `[Char]` with `Data.Text.Internal.Text` (which compiles without the `OverloadedLists` pragma. How to solve?

Comment: I think you've removed the `OverloadedStrings` language extension that was already in your example then. You need that one as well to be able to read `"boolean"` as `Text` instead of `String`.